# Meaning of "just" in "she just doesn't know..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

> She just doesn‘t know how to bring up children.

In the above sentence, what does *just* mean?

Answer (score 27):

The sense of ***[just](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just)*** in the sentence is the following: 
​

> used to make a statement or order stronger, like in:
>
> - He just won't do as he's told.
> - It's just too expensive.

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: This is correct.  "Just" in this context is being used for emphasis or to draw attention to the importance of the associated clause.  When used in a negative context ("He just won't do it") it's often dismissive, reducing the apparent value or credebility of the subject.  In a positive context ("he's just perfect") the context is often exclusionary, brooking no further debate.

Comment: For a little more clarification for OP, you could replace "just" in this usage with "simply" - `She simply doesn't know how to bring up children`. (Yes, the emphasis/meaning is slightly different, but for all practical purposes they'd mean the same thing).  Edit: Didn't see an Answer points this out too...

Answer (score 18):

Expanding on [user070221's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/190842/meaning-of-just-in-she-just-doesnt-know/190844#190844), **it also depends on the context.**

For example, "just" could be used here as a *caveat* (one disadvantage in an otherwise good situation):

> PersonA: Do you think PersonC will be a good mother?
>
> PersonB: Well she keeps her home very organized and can cook healthy meals. She just doesn't know how to bring up children.

Another similar example, where "just" communicates an *excuse*:

> PersonA: My mom was really tough on me as a child. She hurt my feelings a lot.
>
> PersonB: I know, but your mom loves you. She just doesn't know how to bring up children.

There are probably other contexts too but these are the ones I could think of.

Comment: It could also be used to express a degree of either pity or contempt, e.g. "She had a really bad childhood herself, so..." or "We've tried and tried to show her, but..."

Comment: It can also indicate a sense of finality.  In Fellix's example (and without further context), I read it as indicating the woman, in addition to not knowing how to raise kids, is incapable of learning how to raise them.

Answer (score 3):

> No need to accuse her of being cruel or abusive or neglectful or inconsiderate toward her children. She's also not selfish or stupid.
>
> The truth is, she **just** doesn't know how to be a good mother.
>
> I think that as she matures  and with her family's support, the kids will be okay.

The "just" eliminates the other potential causes for the action.

Answer (score 1):

To give a shortcut: uses of 'just' in that form, can normally be replaced by 'simply' without changing the meaning.

> "she simply doesn't know how to be a good mother"

However, 'just' is normally the more friendly version.